# Docker Client is not connecting to its docker daemon on window subsystem

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04, docker-ce

I am using WSL (Window Subsystem for Linux) 2 to install ubuntu and it works fine for me. Next tesk I want to install docker-ce on ubuntu subsystem so that I can do some docker testing. For that I am following this link.
Followed exactly same step mentioned in article. But still my docker client is not connecting to its daemon.

```
https://medium.com/@sebagomez/installing-the-docker-client-on-ubuntus-windows-subsystem-for-linux-612b392a44c4
```

Please see the below image for more information.

[image]

Infact, when I am trying to see the status of docker service using following command then its says "Docker is not running". I explicitly tried to run it but same status.

sudo service docker status

can someone help me on this, what I am missing here. why my docker client is not able to connect its docker daemon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I was able to find the answer for this problem.
I was not running ubuntu subsystem as administrator. Because of that docker daemon was not running. When I was trying to run it explicitly using sudo service docker service it was failing but was not showing any error on console.
Then I used sudo dockerd command for this and it started complaining about cgroup memory issue.
After that I ran it using administrator mode and it worked fine.